# How to save a multipage TIFF image?

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I trying to process a TIFF file using `Image` class:

```cs
using System.Drawing

var i = Image.FromFile("in.tiff");
i.Save("out.tiff");
```

However, when I do it like this, `out.tiff` has only the first page of the multipage `in.tiff`. I know that the information about multiple pages is preserved under `Image`:

```
i.GetFrameCount(Imaging.FrameDimension.Page) // Returns 5, which is the number of pages
```

How can I save `i` as a full TIFF file instead of a part of it?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336508/c-sharp-tesseract-only-scanns-first-tiff-page/70428633#70428633

Comment: From the remarks section: _If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used. When you use the Save method to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file._.... So you need to call an overload that defines the format. `i.Save("out.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);`.

Comment: @dr.null Just tried and still only the first page is saved

Comment: There’s code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388) that saves multi-page TIF. If that doesn’t work for you and you want to consider using a professional imaging library, try the [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS Imaging Pro](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The code to load and save any multi-page format to compressed TIFF is simply `RasterImage img = rasterCodecs.Load("in.tiff", 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.BgrOrGray, 1, -1);` then `rasterCodecs.Save(img, "out.tiff", RasterImageFormat.TifLzw, 0, 1, -1, 1, CodecsSavePageMode.Append);`.

Comment: Right, I missed the multi-frames part. My bad. See [Convert bitmaps to one multipage TIFF image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0).

Comment: Uh oh, looks like it's my first duplicate vote on my own question